# Angular click event in div element not work

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I just want to test the click event in div element and it doesnt works

So here is the part of code in html and ts files :

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-3 mx-auto d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center" 
                style="height: 200px; background-color: rgba(100, 100, 179, 0.1); position: relative;"
                (click)="goToInvoices()"
            >
                <h2>Invoices</h2>
            </div>
```

**TS :**

```
// i've tried to add also :any for return type
goToInvoices() {
  this.router.navigate(['/invoices']).then(nav => {
      console.log(nav); // true if navigation is successful
  }, err => {
     console.log(err) // when there's an error
  });
}
```

In console nav is null !!!

**app.module.ts:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'invoices', component: InvoicesComponent},
];
```

Angular version : 9.1.7

Comment: did you import `RouterModule` inside the component's module ?

Comment: Yes , RouterModule.forRoot(routes)

Comment: You get any error on your console? Did you try to add a breakpoint on your function to see if get in there?

Comment: I rewrite the method like this : goToInvoices() {
    this.router.navigate(['/invoices']).then(nav => {
      console.log(nav); // true if navigation is successful
    }, err => {
      console.log(err) // when there's an error
    });
  }
and in console nav is null i dont know why

Comment: `router-outlet` missing. this is where the routed content get rendered. Check stackBlitz below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `router-outlet`

**Check the following**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6g2tky

Answer (score 0):

On your app.component.html add this :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```